# Can someone explain these JavaScript cookie-functions?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am new to javascript and I came across these functions which, I believe, are for storing a cookie with a name in it (the name being 'value'). I just don't understand it! The functions are as follows:

**Making the cookie**

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+ ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}
```

**Checking wether there is a cookie stored or not**

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length>0) {
        c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1) {
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
            }
        }
    return "";
}
```

There's also a function for displaying a alert-box with the value stored in the cookie, but I'm too lazy to write it down! (I found it in a book)

**EDIT:** I decided to write the last function which displays a welcome message if the cookie is stored and displays a prompt box if it's not set

**Is it set? If so, do "foo". If not, do "bar"**

```
function checkCookie() {
username=getCookie('username');
    if (username!=null && username!="") {
    alert('Welcome again ' + username + '!');
    } else {
    username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
        if (username!=null && username!="") {
        setCookie('username', username,365);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand in these? What is the difficulty you are having?

Comment: Are you looking for a line-by-line explanation of each function?

Comment: I have never understood why JavaScript doesn't have native `setCookie` and `getCookie` functions, forcing people to invent one hundred thousand different ways of walking through `document.cookie`. Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: @Ken Redler that would be nice, but that's probably a little much to ask for :)
@Oded I simply don't understand more than half of it! :)
@Pekka that would be a lot easier if that existed! :)

Comment: `my_username` cookie makes your `getCookie` function wrong...

Comment: @Pekka웃, may be reason is `Javascript is not browser-only language`? Other question: why cookies has magic string presentation, but not some cache-like object?...  :)

Comment: @vp_arth but why would you not need a cookie setting function on server side? (Apart from that - browser-side Javascript is arguably full of browser-only APIs and methods, so you'd think there could be one for cookies, too.)

Comment: @Pekka웃, I use js-engine as my everyday worker) scripts, deploying etc... I think, it's good, that ECMAscript not includes entities like cookies, window... or as you want `native setCookie and getCookie functions`; Also, browsers not modify js-engine's interface, only add some browser specific predefined entities, and yes, it can be some cookie-related functions) but I think, it should be a simple object with simple interface, not any number of functions... Oh, how many letters for comment :)

Comment: I use `cookie = {get: function(key), set: function(key, value, options), del: function(key), all: function()}` interface, for example

Comment: @vp_arth OK, I should have been more precise - *browsers* should arguably offer something here. Not ECMAScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the cookie:

Let's say you want to set a cookie called "favoriteColor" with the value "blue" that expires in a week.  The code you want to run is

```
document.cookie="favoriteColor=blue;expires=Mon, 16 Aug 2010 23:59:59 GMT";
```

The function setCookie that you posted is designed to generate that line of code.  It generates the date based on the period you give it, it escapes the text of the value, and concatenates the results to create the document.cookie string.

The only remaining tricky bit is that the expiredays parameter is optional; the line that creates the document.cookie string includes a conditional that checks whether expiredays exists, and doesn't include the "expires" part of the string if expiredays doesn't exist.  This uses the "ternary operator": `(expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString()` means "if expiredays is null, use the empty string, otherwise use ';expires="+exdate.toGMTString()'".

The second piece of code you posted is looking for the cookie by searching the set of cookies (which is a single string) for the name given (followed by =) and returning the text from that point up to the next semicolon.  So it can pick "blue" out of

"favoriteBand=Foreigner;favoriteColor=blue;favoriteFood=sushi;".

Answer (score 2):

The document's cookies are stored in a long cookie string. These functions parse out the separate cookie values. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.cookie) for an explanation of how the string is structured.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to [read a little bit](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) on what cookies are and how they work.

In the cookie you have `name:value` pairs of the actual data and some metadata, such as the cookies expiration date.